# How to add a custom JS file into a angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an angular project with my friends for our class project and we want a custom Js file with certain methods to be added to our project but adding this to the app.component.html file inside  didn't work.
How to add the files to the project?

Comment: If you used angular CLI to build the project, you need to add this configuration in the `angular.json` file as explained here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Answer (score 4):

you can do this in two ways:

If you want the custom js to be global, add the path to scripts array in **angular-cli.json** file

```
"scripts": [
    "../custom" 
 ];
```

Otherwise if you want the custom js to be in specific component,

```
import * as custom from './custom';
custom.method();
```

Answer (score 0):

`firsfile` and `secondfile` are the member variable of typescript class

```
Initalise this member var in constructor like this.
this.firstFile= require('./firstfile'); // firstfile.js
this.secondFile= require('./secondfile'); //secondfile.js
```

now use same as you do in JavaScript after importing module files.

Hope it will help

Comment: I don't think so is their is any wrong in that . I am also use some protobuffer JavaScript file in my angular project , it run fine. so if you give any negative rating then please explain it why you are giving the negative rating.